# javaScript window.crypto.getRandomvalues is not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me to resolve my issue. I have used javaScript window.crypto.getRandomvalues function is working in all browser expect safari web browser and my safari browser version 5.1.7. Please find my code

```
    if ("crypto" in window && "getRandomValues" in crypto) 
            rand = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] % 16|0;
        else rand = Math.random() * 16 | 0;
        return hexs[i === 19 ? rand & 0x3 | 0x8 : rand];
    })
```

Please find the screenshot. this is my error:
[screenshot][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1aYk.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues):

> The array given as the parameter is filled with random numbers.

which does NOT mean it returns an array filled with random numbers.
So, change your code like this:

```
if ("crypto" in window && "getRandomValues" in crypto){
  var arr = new Uint8Array(1);
  crypto.getRandomValues(arr)
  rand = arr[0] % 16|0;
}
```